# Macros as arguments to preprocessor directives

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

Being faced with the question whether it's possible to choose `#include`s in the preprocessor I immediately thought *not possible*.
.. Only to later find out that it is indeed possible and you only need to watch out for argument expansions (which e.g. Boost.Preprocessor can take care of).

While I'd avoid actually doing that for includes if possible, I'd like to know why this works. At the moment I fail to get a useful understanding in the C++ or **C** standard.
Are parameterized macros allowed for any preprocessor-directive? (except `#define`/`#undef`)
Can someone reference where this is allowed and summarize it?

*Example for the curious utilizing Boost.Preprocessor for simplicity:*

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/cat.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/stringize.hpp>

#define INC_LOCAL(a,b)  BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(BOOST_PP_CAT(BOOST_PP_CAT(a,b),.h))
#define INC_GLOBAL(a,b) BOOST_PP_CAT(BOOST_PP_CAT(<,a),BOOST_PP_CAT(b,>))

#include INC_LOCAL(loc,al)   // #include "local.h"
#include INC_GLOBAL(vect,or) // #include <vector>
```

*Update*: 
Referenced **C** standard, clarified question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From § 16.2-4 ("Source file inclusion") of C++ 2003 draft:

> A preprocessing directive of the form
>
> ```
> # include pp-tokens new-line
> ```
>
> (that does not match one of the two previous forms) is permitted. The preprocessing tokens after `include` in the directive are processed just as in normal text (each identifier currently defined as a macro name is replaced by its replacement list of preprocessing tokens).

§ 6.10.2-4 of C99 says the same.

The "two previous forms" mentioned above are `# include <h-char-sequence>` and `# include "q-char-sequence"`. The section seems too simple to summarize.

For other directives, macro expansion isn't performed on any `identifier` preprocessing token (note this behavior is not defined by the grammar, but by C++ § 16 / C § 6.10):

```
# if constant-expression new-line [group] 
# ifdef identifier new-line [group] 
# ifndef identifier new-line [group] 
# elif constant-expression new-line [group] 
# else new-line [group] 
# endif new-line 
# include pp-tokens new-line 
# define identifier replacement-list new-line 
# define identifier lparen [identifier-list] ) replacement-list new-line 
# undef identifier new-line 
# line pp-tokens new-line 
# error [pp-tokens] new-line 
# pragma [pp-tokens] new-line 
# new-line
```

`#line` is explicitly macro-expanded by C++ § 16.4-5 / C § 6.10.4-5. Expansion for `#error` (C++ § 16.5 / C § 6.10.5) and `#pragma` (C++ § 16.6 / C § 6.10.6) isn't mentioned. C++ § 16.3-7 / C 6.10.3-8 states:

> If a # preprocessing token, followed by an identifier, occurs lexically at the point at which a preprocessing directive could begin, the identifier is not subject to macro replacement.

C++ § 16.3.1 / C § 6.10.3.1-1 tells us that when the arguments to a macro function are substituted into the `replacement-list`, they are first macro expanded. Similarly, C++ § 16.3.4 / C § 6.10.3.4 has the preprocessor macro-expand the `replacement-list` after substitution.

In summary, macro expansion is done for `#if`, `#elif`, `#include`, `#line`, the arguments to a macro function and the body of a macro function when substituted. I think that's everything.

Comment: Well, `pp-tokens` gets me to `preprocessing-token`, from where only `preprocessing-op-or-punc` looks good but only gives some operators.

Comment: So `are processed just as in normal text` implies macro expansion on something like `identifier(identifier, ...)`?

Comment: Sure. The result might have undefined behavior.

Comment: I'm glad you could understand anything... though I do use BOOST_PP macros from time to time, it's all magic to me! I guess I'll have to read and reread this response over and over :/

Comment: Reading standards is a learned skill. The more you're exposed to it, the easier it gets. The same is true of any discourse.

Comment: I hope so, i'm working on it since i have my copy. Its certainly better then always acting on the "somebody said this works" premise.

Answer (score 2):

It's a very fundamental feature of the C preprocessor -- for example, a directive such as `#ifdef` makes zero sense **except** when used with an argument that's possibly a macro (if you had to know that the argument is not allowed to be a macro, what could the purpose of `#ifdef` possibly **be**?!).

I'm not sure how chapter and verse of the ISO C standard would help you -- the C++ standard, as I recall, does not change the preprocessor's operation anyway.

Comment: Correction: i'm now confused wether parameterized macros are simply allowed in any pp-directive and wanted to clearify that.