# Can I use a preprocessor variable in #include directive?

Tags: c++

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
$ c++ -D GENERATED=build/generated-content main.cpp
```

My `main.cpp` file:

```
#include "GENERATED/header.h"
void f() { /* something */ }
```

Currently this code fails to compile. How should I fix it? And whether it's possible at all?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems you want to use different headers depending on some "compilation profile".

Instead of the `-D`solution, I would rather suggest using the `-I` directive to specify the include directories.

Given you have the following file tree:

```
/
  debug/
    header.h
  release/
    header.h
```

`main.cpp`:

```
#include "header.h"

/* some instructions, not relevant here */
```

And in your `Makefile` (or whatever tool you use), just specify the proper **include directory** to use, depending on whatever reason you want:

```
g++ -I debug main.cpp // Debug mode

g++ -I release main.cpp // Release mode
```

*Important foot note:* I don't know if you intended to use this as a *debug/release* switch. However, doing so would be weird: the interface (the included `.h` files) shouldn't change between `release` and `debug`. If you ever need this, the usual way is to enable/disable some parts of the code using defines, mostly in `.c` (and `.cpp`) files.

Answer (score 6):

You can't do that directly, but this is possible:

```
c++ -D "GENERATED=\"build/generated-content\"" main.cpp  

#define INCLUDE_NAME() GENERATED "/header.h"
#include INCLUDE_NAME()
```

---

EDIT: **This solution does not work (see the comments below)**.

Essentially, any `#include` statement not conforming to the 'normal' syntax (either `#include ""` or `#include <>`) but being of the form `#include SOMETHING` will cause SOMETHING to be preprocessed, after which it has to conform to one of the 'normal' syntaxes. SOMETHING can be any sequence of pp-tokens.

However in this case, the result (as generated by GCC) is...

`#include "build/generated-content" "/header.h"`

... which does not conform to one of the 'normal' syntaxes.

Comment: That is crazy and gives me very evil ideas. Is it standard? Hard to Google for.

Comment: Yep, that's standard (clause [16.2.4]). I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @int: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736654/macros-as-arguments-to-preprocessor-directives).

Comment: hkaiser, using GCC this results in `#include "build/generated-content" "/header.h"` which doesn't work.

Comment: Ooops, you're right. As I wrote above, after preprocessing it has to conform to one of the 'normal' syntaxes... And string concatenation happens after preprocessing. I'll think about an alternative solution.

Comment: If I understand correctly the comments, it is a good idea, which doesn’t work. Could you edit your answer to show that? People might skip reading comments and lose time.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that is covered in the C++ Standard, so it would be up to the individual compiler vender whether or not to support it.  I don't think any do.

However, just about every compiler allows you to specify a search directory for headers.  It's usually the /i option.

So it would be:

```
$ c++ -i build/generated-content main.cpp 
My main.cpp file:

#include "header.h" 
void f() { /* something */ }
```